# What preposition to use for an object that's melting?

Tags: prepositions, word-request

Example sentence:

> We stood before the bonfire watching the bottle melt __ flames.

I thought *among* was the word, but if you search for *melt among X* on Google you get zero results.

What the correct preposition?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is the sun itself melting? Is the sun melting something else?  If the latter, what?  Your desire to use "melt among" implies the sun is not melting the clouds. A sentence which would make sense to me would be something like, "The child watched the sun melt ice on the sidewalk." Note there is no preposition needed between *sun* and *melt*.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Are the cloud the cause of the sun melting, does the sun make the clouds melt? Maybe try an easier example, with a metal object or something.

Comment: If you don't mean that the sun is literally melting (dissolving) but rather using it metaphorically to mean that it's setting, then I would say "melt into burning clouds".  (This is a guess, since a sun can't actually melt -- that implies going from a solid state to liquid, but a sun is a ball of gas and plasma.)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I updated the example

Comment: This question bothers me because a normal bonfire isn't hot enough to melt glass.  A very hot bonfire can get up to 1100° C, but glass melts at 1400° C

Comment: @Andrew - That's the temperature to completely liquify, though; they start softening long before that.  I've personally seen glass bottles slump and deform in ordinary campfires.

Comment: @Andrew - [Not all bottles are made of glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGX_XFPsik0).

Comment: @stangdon now I know what I'm trying at my next bonfire.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the preposition you want is **into**:

TFD shows:

> **melt into something**
>
> to melt and change into a different state
>   *All the ice cream melted into a sticky soup*.

Oxford Learner's Dictionary shows a more figurative usage:

> **melt into something**
>
> to gradually become part of something and therefore become difficult to see
>   *Once the introductions had been made, she melted into the background*.

So, if you mean to say that the bottle started to literally melt and then gradually be consumed by the fire (I am imagining a plastic bottle here), then you could indeed say:

> *We stood before the bonfire watching the bottle melt **into** flames.*

---

For the record, I thought your original was just fine, although I would have used an article:

> We stood on the hill watching the sun melt into *the* burning clouds.

Some people had trouble with this, but I think they were thinking too literally. A sentence like that could be used to describe a sunset like this:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps "melt into *the* flames"? The bottle doesn't become flames, which is what is implied without the article.

Comment: @Catija - I was imagining a plastic bottle that could catch fire. Your version would indeed be better for a glass bottle that is melting but not burning.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for updating the example; it's clearer now.  To melt **among** the flames is OK, but if you mean "in the middle of", a better choice might be [**amid** or **amidst**](http://blog.dictionary.com/amidst-vs-amid/).  If you means the bottle slumps down into the flames, or turns into flames, then **into** is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

*To melt* can be transitive or intransitive. In its transitive form, it's either:

> We stood before the bonfire watching the flames melt the bottle.

or

> We stood before the bonfire watching the bottle being melted by the flames.

Now I see what you meant when you said you wanted to use "among" with the intransitive form of "to melt", but I don't think it's idiomatic.

Comment: Are you sure? I get some Google hits: "melt into burning" https://www.google.com.tw/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22melt%20into%20burning%22&oq=%22melt%20into%20burning%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.616j0j9

Comment: @alex Well, yeah that exists, but it means something else. "A melts into burning B" means that by melting, A is turned into B. For example: "The bottle melts into burning glass". It's not a perfect example but you get the idea.

Comment: "Melt" can be intransitive, though.